# Javascript read table and if value != null get rows data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I read a table using Javascript and lookup on each Row from the table if the value of [X] cell in the row is != null, save that row data.

Currently I've just found how to read the whole table using this script

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">



    <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td id="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" id="txtID" value="100"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td id="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" id="txtID" value="200"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td id="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" id="txtID" value=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


<script>
var myTab = document.getElementById('tableID');
        var tableData = [];
    // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
    for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
        if(){

        }else{

        }
    }
</script>
```

Can I get help to complete the syntax of the script or can I get some direction on how to solve this

In this table example, the output or the rows that shall be grabbed would be the first 2 tr's since they are != null

Comment: Using getDocumentById is very slow, it would be much better to send the data as JSON in the page and then render that into a table

Comment: @DavidBradshaw how would you recommend me to do that? I mean how do I approach that solution

Comment: I don't understand the last line of the question. None of the rows are null. Do you mean the value of the hidden input?

Comment: You shouldn't repeat `id=txtID`. IDs are supposed to be unique. Use a class for repeated labels like that.

Comment: @IceeFrog personally I would use React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the attribute [***id***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in document, use [***`class`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead.

You can use [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target the inputs whose value is not null using attribute selector. Then use [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like the following way:

```js
var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""])');
var tableData = Array.from(myTab).map(input => input.value);
console.log(tableData);
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td class="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" class="txtID" value="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td class="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" class="txtID" value="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td class="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" class="txtID" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**: You can get all the cell value in the form of objects like the following way:

```js
var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr .txtID:not([value=""])');
var tableData = [];
Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => {
  var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
  var obj = {};
  obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
  obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
  obj.C = tds[2].textContent;
  obj.D = tds[3].textContent;
  obj.E = input.value;
  tableData.push(obj);
});
console.log(tableData);
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td class="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" class="txtID" value="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td class="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" class="txtID" value="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td class="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" class="txtID" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer sir, it does help me understand the syntax you used because previous answer does it without using IDs and I tho it was only gonna be possible this way thanks!

Comment: @IceeFrog, please notice the update in the answer where you actually do not need the if condition at all:)

Comment: Wow that reduced the code length by a lot, sexy I'll grab this thanks a lot sir

Comment: hey sir is there a way to extend the script in order to add ALL the row data from the tr's that do have a value in txtID? for example, Output: row1 [A: "val1", B: "val2", C: "val3", D: "500", E: "100"] row2 [A: "val1", B: "val2", C: "val3", D: "500", E: "200"], output is just an example I mean it's not like I wish to be it that way I just thought it would be easier to explain the desired output using that format

Comment: @IceeFrog, I have added another answer, hope that helps:)

Comment: I want to cry of joy, thanks a lot really *inserts cute pet picture* I can't stop saying thanks really thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

Use `cells` to get the cells of the row, and then get the value of the input in `cells[4]`. If it's not an empty string, save it to the array.

```js
var myTab = document.getElementById('tableID');
var tableData = [];
// LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
for (var i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
  var val = myTab.rows[i].cells[4].firstElementChild.value;
  if (val != '') {
    tableData.push(val);
  }
}
console.log(tableData);
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="tableID">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td id="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" id="txtID" value="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td id="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" id="txtID" value="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>val1</td>
      <td>val2</td>
      <td>val3</td>
      <td>1500</td>
      <td id="myID"><input type="hidden" name="txtID" id="txtID" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```